# How can I upload a entire folder to GitHub from my mobile phone?

Tags: github

When I search or ask for how to upload folder to GitHub from my mobile phone. Everyone is tell that you can only upload entrie folder on desktop or laptop computer. Please help me

Comment: Do you mean from the GitHub app?

Comment: You first need to make a Git commit containing the folder (and/or changes to the folder) and then push the commit.

Comment: @hololeap, this question seems to be specificly about mobile phones.

Comment: @OctopuSS7 Fair enough, but my comment applies either way, right?

Comment: I guess so, although I'd assume someone asking the question would know that. In that case, I should probably add the specific commands to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is only if you are on Android.

1. Find a terminal emulator like Termux.
2. Grant the emulator storage access.
3. Move all the relevant files into a new folder.
4. Install git, using whatever package manager you have (pkg or apt-get both work on Termux).
5. Create a git remote on the GitHub website or app.
6. Use your normal git commands to add the folder.